# Java - Tokenizing by regex

Tags: java, regex, tokenize, stringtokenizer

Im trying to tokenize strings of the following format:

```
"98, BA71V-CP204L (p32, p30), BA71V-CP204L (p32, p30), , 0, 125900, 126505"
"91, BA71V-B175L, BA71V-B175L, , 0, 108467, 108994,   -, 528, 528"
```

Each of the tokens will then be stored in a string array. The strings are to be tokenized by "," excluding those that are inside ( , ) so that the contents of ( , ) would belong in a token. The tokens may also only contain a space.

Im thinking the reg-ex would find a comma, then check if it is surrounded on the left by a opening parenthesis, and on the right by an closing parenthesis. Since this comma is contained by some (  ), it would not be used to tokenize.

I could have a regex for the opposite, but what about the time where neither sides of the delimiter contain "(" or ")"?

Currently am using:

```
StringTokenizer tokaniza = new StringTokenizer(content,","); //no regex
```

but i feel as though regex go better with

```
content.split();
```

Comment: Do you know what the entire range of acceptable characters in the token is?  uppercase? lower? punctuation?

Comment: Could be anything really regarding case/characters. Only symbols would be "+" or "-" which would be between 2 delimiters on its own, like in the second line above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead assertion.

```
String s = "98, BA71V-CP204L (p32, p30), BA71V-CP204L (p32, p30), , 0, 125900, 126505";
String parts[] = s.split(",(?![^()]*\\))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output:

```
[98,  BA71V-CP204L (p32, p30),  BA71V-CP204L (p32, p30),  ,  0,  125900,  126505]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a split using:

```
(?<!\(\w{1,4}),(?!\s*\w*\)).*?
```

The only thing, Java doesn't support infinite repetitions inside look-behinds you have to specify the number of characters inside the parenthesis (i.e. \w{1,4}). In other words this will break if your characters inside of the parenthesis exceed 4.